# Get list of running MetroStyle apps

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I was wondering whether it's possible to get the list of running MetroStyle apps in a C# Metro app or not. I'm looking to do this in Windows 8 (not Windows Phone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. That would be a breach of sandbox. You don't want some random app getting information about the apps you run and reporting it home.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Anyone attempting to gather this information can easily use it for evil.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of creating a Full-Screen MetroApp switcher. (Something like StartScreen, but for running apps). Isn't it possible?

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/a9e0ebe7-567a-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8 I'm thinking to create a similar app for Windows 8 but just for running apps. Since they're similar, I figured maybe it's possible to do sth like that in Windows 8.

Comment: Unfortunately creating applications with access to sensitive system resources is not supported right now (in Metro). You could ask Microsoft to consider allowing access to some system level APIs with appropriate user permissions in future releases of Windows RT.

Answer (score 4):

I'm writing an Alt-Tab gesture alternative with Delphi, so this is the way I found to list running ModernUI (once known Metro) applications, I tested it with Windows 8 Release Preview only, I don't know if it still works on Windows 8 RTM.

```
procedure ShowRunningModernUIApps;
var
  metroapp:hwnd;
  strAppTitle: array[0..MAX_PATH]of char;
  h:integer;
  strListApps:string;
begin
  metroapp:=FindWindow('Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow',nil);
  if metroapp <>0 then
  begin
    GetWindowText(metroapp,strAppTitle,MAX_PATH);
    strListApps:='Running ModernUI Apps : '+strAppTitle;
    h:=0;
    while h=0 do
    begin
      metroapp:=FindWindowEx(0,metroapp,'Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow',nil);
      if metroapp<>0 then
      begin
        GetWindowText(metroapp,strAppTitle,MAX_PATH);
        strListApps:=strListApps+','+strAppTitle;
      end
      else h:=1; //let's finish the search loop

    end;
  end;
  ShowMessage(strListApps);

end;
```

This shows the current running ModernUI application's titles, you can store their HWND however you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to get the list in a Metro app, not a desktop app.

Comment: I see, as they say that's not allowed, but I think that an alternative way could be using a websockets communication with a service or application (websockets server) that can access to that information, list the apps and return them to your metro app with Windows.Networking.Sockets, and also send commands to switch to them. At least that would work on Windows x86/x64 I don't know about a Windows8 for ARM. That could be an alternative, maybe annoying but it works.

Comment: Yes. I have created such application. I think that would work. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I need to find documentation on this, but I've heard that using a workaround like a middle tier service on the computer  would cause your app to be denied in the store (if that's how you intended on distributing it).  You're basically using a method to get around the API exclusion (which will work technically).